# What is the difference between"Pod The node had condition: [DiskPressure]" and "The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage"

Tags: kubernetes

When the pod is Evicted by disk issue, I found there are two reasons:

1. The node had condition: `[DiskPressure]`
2. The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container NAME was using 16658224Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

I found [Node conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-conditions) for `DiskPressure`.

What is the difference?

Comment: Did you get these errors after the same operation?

Comment: There are two Evicted pods, one with error 1, and the other with error 2. I know both of the are disk issue, but not sure if the operations are the same. Maybe log file is too large.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both reasons are caused by the same error - that the worker node has ran out of disk space. However, the difference is when they are exactly happening.

To answer this question I decided to dig inside [Kubernetes source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes).

Starting with `The node had condition: [DiskPressure]` error.

We can find that it is used in `pkg/kubelet/eviction/helpers.go` file, [line 44](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/kubelet/eviction/helpers.go#L44):

```
nodeConditionMessageFmt = "The node had condition: %v. "
```

This variable is used by `Admit` function in `pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go` file, [line 137](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2ba872513da76568274885f8c5736b415a77b0cd/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L137).

`Admit` function is used by `canAdmitPod` function in `pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go` file,  [line 1932](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/047a6b9f861b2cc9dd2eea77da752ac398e7546f/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L1932):

`canAdmitPod` function is used by `HandlePodAdditions` function, also in the `kubelet.go` file, [line 2195](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/047a6b9f861b2cc9dd2eea77da752ac398e7546f/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L2195).

Comments in the code in `Admit` and `canAdmitPod` functions:

> canAdmitPod determines if a pod can be admitted, and gives a reason if it cannot. "pod" is new pod, while "pods" are all admitted pods.
> The function returns a boolean value indicating whether the pod can be admitted, a brief single-word reason and a message explaining why the pod cannot be admitted.

and

> Check if we can admit the pod; if not, reject it.

So based on this analysis we can conclude that `The node had condition: [DiskPressure]` error message happens when kubelet agent won't admit **new** pods on the node, that means they won't start.

---

Now moving on to the second error - `The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container NAME was using 16658224Ki, which exceeds its request of 0`

Similar as before, we can find it in `pkg/kubelet/eviction/helpers.go` file, [line 42](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/kubelet/eviction/helpers.go#L42):

```
nodeLowMessageFmt  =  "The node was low on resource: %v. "
```

This variable is used in the same file by `evictionMessage` function, [line 1003](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/kubelet/eviction/helpers.go#L1003).

`evictionMessage` function is used by `synchronize` function in `pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go` file, [line 231](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L231)

`synchronize` function is used by `start` function, in the same file, [line 177](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2ba872513da76568274885f8c5736b415a77b0cd/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L177).

Comments in the code in the `synchronize` and `start` functions:

> synchronize is the main control loop that enforces eviction thresholds.
> Returns the pod that was killed, or nil if no pod was killed.

> Start starts the control loop to observe and response to low compute resources.

So we can conduct that the error `The node was low on resource:` error message happens when kubelet agent decides to kill currently **running** pods on the node.

---

It is worth emphasising that both error messages comes from node conditions (which are set in function `synchronize`, [line 308](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/2ba872513da76568274885f8c5736b415a77b0cd/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L308), to the values detected by eviction manager). Then kubelet's agent makes the decisions that results in these two error messages.

---

**To sum up**:

Both errors are due to insufficient disk space, but:

- `The node had condition:` error is related to the pods that are **about to start** on the node, but they can't
- `The node was low on resource:` error is related to the **currently running pods** that must be terminated

Answer (score 0):

Both reasons refer to the same cause where the underlying worker node has ran out of disk space.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Is there any difference?

Comment: In this case no difference, you need to dealt with the disk space issue at [node level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage) now. You can resize the disk if your storage driver (or cloud provider) supports that. Then check the container is it justifiable to hold 16Gi of storage? Does it allows to grow further? You can then look into other types (eg. NFS) of volume depends on the justification.

Answer (score 0):

For the second error you mentioned, it's caused by too much stuff in `emptyDir` or too much logs of the pods

But I have no idea if the second error could also trigger the first one...